# How to reinstall Mac OS X from Ubuntu

Tags: macos, imac, install, unix

I bought a 2010 iMac (iMac11,2) at an op shop today, to upgrade from my 2007. All fine, except it's (solely) running Ubuntu (turn it on, you hear the Mac boot up sound and a second later it's the black screen with an underscore). I don't know the first thing about Ubuntu and have no interest in it, I'd just like to use it as a regular Mac. How do I do that?

**Cheers**

Comment: If you can not install OS X or macOS by using Internet Recovery and your 2007 Mac is still running, then post a comment. There should be a way to use your 2007 Mac to install macOS on the 2011 Mac.